# Generator not evaluating promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Why doesn't the generator wait for the asynchronous prm promise to complete before moving on to the next yield?

```
function *verify() {
    try {
        let prm = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            resolve("abc");
        })
        let k = yield prm
        console.log(k)
        yield 1;
        console.log("1")
        yield 2;
        console.log("2")
        yield 3;
        console.log("3")
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error")
    }
}

var gen = verify()
while (!gen.next().done) {}
```

returns

```
undefined
1
2
3
```

Comment: Generators don't wait for promises. You are thinking of async generators, which are not yet supported, but you can transpile with Babel.

Comment: Because a promise is considered async, so prm will be set then yielded but it will resolve *anytime*, it's not blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a generator - on its own - doesn't wait for anything. It just emits what you were `yield`ing from the `next()` call. You could of course have your loop wait when before calling `next` again when it gets a promise.

What you are thinking of is `async`/`await`. You want to write

```
async function verify() {
    try {
        let prm = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            resolve("abc");
        })
        let k = await prm
        console.log(k)
        console.log("1")
        console.log("2")
        console.log("3")
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error")
    }
}

var prm = verify();
```