# how generate step by step call generator function in redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

```
function* mySaga() {

    const score1 = yield*  call(asyncTsec, 3);
    yield put({type:'ADD_ARTIST' , payload:score1 })

    const score2 = yield*  call(asyncTsec, 1);
    yield put({type:'ADD_ARTIST' , payload:score2 })

    const score3 = yield*  call(asyncTsec, 2);
    yield put({type:'ADD_ARTIST' , payload:score3 });
}
```

how generate step by step call this function by redux-saga  like example ?

```
function* logGenerator() {
  console.log(yield);
  console.log(yield);
  console.log(yield);
}

var gen = logGenerator();


gen.next(); 
gen.next('pretzel'); // pretzel
gen.next('california'); // california
gen.next('mayonnaise'); // mayonnaise
```

Answer (score 1):

> how generate step by step call this function by redux-saga like example ?

For a start it is obviously necessary to separate that does redux-saga with effects and that is feature of generator functions. From caller side each generator is just a function which returns an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterators), and from internal behavior it's interruptible function with saving/resuming point of execution.

`Redux-saga` is just a way to describe asynchronous processes in yieldable style, depend on supposed effects list. Every yield action, like `yield call(...)` or `yield put(...)` just returns [special object](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/src/internal/io.js#L24), depend on which [saga process manager](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/src/internal/scheduler.js) performs real action, for example, waiting promises / async functions, and return result into `next` step of generator function.

So simplest saga-like process manager can be rewritten as following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47302202/7878274. It does not support `yield*` operator, but can be easily added with `if`-branch with duck-typing check on returning `Iterable` object